# Update UpdatePanel without a control?

Tags: c#, timer, updatepanel

I currently have a process that does the following:

1. Read a remote file and parse complex data;
2. Dynamically create a bitmap image based on the data;
3. Display the bitmap in an Image control in an Updatepanel.
4. Wait 15 seconds, then repeat the whole process.

I have set `myScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(myTimer)`, and run the whole process (all three steps in sequence) on `myTimer_Tick`, and I have set the timer's Interval to 15 seconds, which is ideal for my purposes. However, step 1 above could take as long as a minute (in very rare cases), and I'm not entirely sure what will happen in that case? What will happen if the `myTimer_Tick` fires after 15 seconds and start it all again, when the previous run hasn't completed?

Ideally I'd like to update the UpdatePanel programmatically when the last line of code for Steps 1 to 3 have been finished, and then use Thread.Sleep to pause for 14 seconds before repeating, as it usually takes about 1 second to do steps1-3. However, I have no idea how to make the UpdatePanel update without linking it to a control. Why can't I just say `myUpdatePanel.Upate()` at the end of any chunk of code?

Comment: In these kind of situations you stop the timer immidiately upon entering(myTimer_Tick), and start again when you finish step 3. myTimer_Tick fires every 15 sec either you are still inside or not.

Comment: This feels like a very stupid question, but how do I start and stop the timer? There doesn't appear to be a myTimer.Stop method?

Comment: OK, got it. myTimer.Enabled = false stops it, and true starts it. Thanks for the advice, everything is working now.